# Process CSV files in location relative to rake task

Tags: ruby-on-rails, csv, ruby-on-rails-4, rake, rake-task

I have a `rake` task and CSV files that I need to process; they are located in sub-directory of the `lib\tasks` directory:

```
\foo
  one.csv
  two.csv
  ...
  foo.rake
```

The task:

```
task foo: :environment do

  # for each file in directory
  Dir.foreach("./*.csv") do |file|   # not valid

    # process CSV file's content
    CSV.foreach(file, {:headers => true, :col_sep => ";"}) do |row|
      ...
    end

  end # Dir

end # task
```

How do I references files that are relative to the rake task?

Comment: Could you use [`File.join`](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.2/File.html#method-c-join) to get file path? Something like `start_dir = File.join(Rails.root, "lib", "tasks")`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I got to thinking about this more and I think combining [`File.join`](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.2/File.html#method-c-join) and [`Dir.glob`](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.2/Dir.html#method-c-glob) will allow you to process all your csv files:

```
require "csv"

foo_dir = File.join(Rails.root, "lib", "tasks", "foo")

task foo: :environment do

  # for each file in directory
  Dir.glob(foo_dir + "/*.csv") do |csv_file|

    # process CSV file's content
    CSV.foreach(csv_file, {:headers => true, :col_sep => ";"}) do |row|
      #...
    end

  end # Dir

end # task
```

---

**EDIT:** As @craig pointed out in the comment below, this can be accomplished more succinctly by using [`File.dirname`](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.2/File.html#method-c-dirname) and `__FILE__`:

```
require "csv"

task foo: :environment do

  # for each file in directory
  Dir.glob(File.dirname(__FILE__) + "/*.csv").each do |file|

    # process CSV file's content
    CSV.foreach(csv_file, {:headers => true, :col_sep => ";"}) do |row|
      #...
    end

  end # Dir

end # task
```

Comment: So, `rake` can't infer the script's location?

Comment: Proper syntax is `Dir.glob(File.dirname(__FILE__) + "/*.csv").each do |file|`.  Update you answer and I accept it.